# Linq: Get rows where values exists in another table

Tags: c#, linq

I have two tables in my database:

```
TableA:
Id, ColA, ColB, Value   IsSelectable
1   A     B     value1  False
2   C     D     value2  True
3   K     M     value3  True

TableB:
Id, ColA, ColB
1   A     B
2   K     M
```

Now I want to create a Linq query that select all rows from TableA that are: IsSelectable = true and where ColA equals ColA in TableB AND ColB equals ColB in TableB.

In above example I would like to return row # 3 as this is the only one that fullfills my requirements.

I have tried this:

```
from ta in _db.TableA
from tb in _db.TableB
where ta.IsSelectable == true
&& (ta.ColA == tb.ColA && ta.ColB == tb.ColB)
select ta;
```

Problem with above query is that the query times out if I tries to show its values in the debugger.

I have also tried to join the two tables where I join TableA to TableB. But when trying to select TableA from the joined result, I cannot create a new TableA record, as my Id is database created and has no setter.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
from ta in _db.TableA
from t in _db.TableB on new {a=ta.ColA,b=ta.ColB} equals new{a= t.ColA,b=t.ColB} 
into tc from tb in tc
where ta.IsSelectable == true
select ta;
```

Comment: Yes it works! Thank you... My problems was that I didn't know how to combine the fields in the join. So thank you for teaching me that :-)